# Loading a page with values from multiple tables using a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I want to do is to have a number of labels populate with information from 2 different tables.  When the submit button is pressed, it will then hit my Post method and save the info the user typed in and the info automatically populated to the db, but I'm having issues with my Get method.  My Get method in my controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddOrganization(int peopleID = 1)
    {
        var peopleModel = db.People.Include("EmployeeContacts").Single(g => g.PeopleID == peopleID);
        return View("../Setup/AddOrganization", peopleModel);
    }
```

However, I've got a viewModel that looks like this and includes all the tables that will be needed for the Get and Post methods for this page:

```
    public class AddOrganizationViewModel
    {
        public MusicStore.Models.Organizations Organizations { get; set; }
        public MusicStore.Models.People People { get; set; }
        public MusicStore.Models.OrganizationOptions OrganizationsOptions { get; set; }
        public MusicStore.Models.EmployeeContacts EmployeeContacts { get; set; }
    }
```

So when the view is first loaded, and the Get method above is called, I get an error saying

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.People_8080C33752A42A0C994331F5015BCCFCEB99B3ECD7AB8CA2BB11ABE67851B81B', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MusicStore.ViewModels.AddOrganizationViewModel'.
```

Here is my view also:

```
<h2>AddOrganization</h2>
@model MusicStore.ViewModels.AddOrganizationViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "AddOrganization"))
{
<fieldset>
<legend>CONTACT INFORMATION</legend>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Organization Name")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Organizations.OrgName)
</div>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Phone Number")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Organizations.OrgPhone)
</div>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Point of Contact")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Organizations.OrgPointOfContact)
</div>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Office Location")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Organizations.OrgOfficeLocation)
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>FIRST EMPLOYEE OF ORGANIZATION</legend>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Admin First Name")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.People.FirstName)
</div>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Admin Last Name")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.People.LastName)
</div>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Admin NID")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.People.NID)
</div>
<div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Admin SID")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.People.SID)
</div>
 <div class ="editor-label">
     @Html.Label("Admin Email")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EmployeeContacts.Email)
</div>
 <div class ="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Admin Phone Number")
</div>
 <div class ="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EmployeeContacts.PrimaryPhone)
</div>
```

How do I send the needed information to the view via the Get method when it can only take a ViewModel type?  Is there a way I can add this information to my ViewModel?  Any help or shove in the right direction would great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var peopleModel = db.People.Include("EmployeeContacts").Single(g => g.PeopleID == peopleID);
```

what is the type of `peopleModel` in this case?

Seeing as you are returning it directly from a database, it looks like it has not yet been 'converted' or 'projected' into the actual viewmodel that the view expects.

you will probably need to do something like this:

```
AddOrganizationViewModel vm  = new AddOrganizationViewModel();
vm.Organizations = new Organizations()
{
someOrganizationProperty = peopleModel.SomeProperty,
};
vm.People = new People()
{
somePeopleProperty = peopleModel.SomeOtherProperty,
};
//etc for the other properties and types in your viewmodel
```

when all that data has been set, you can return the `AddOrganizationViewModel`.

Comment: That worked exactly as I had hoped!  Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var peopleModel = db.People.Include("EmployeeContacts").Single(g => g.PeopleID == peopleID);
```

This doesn't create an `AddOrganizationViewModel` object. Either add a `Select` clause at the end or use the data in that object to populate a new viewmodel.